# Java how to keep same windows layout after a program restart

Tags: java

Hi I have a java GUI application which shows table and allow user to move column and resize them. The problem is that each time I exit and restart the application, column place and size are back to default. Is there a mean to keep it as what it was before exiting the application?
any link to ref on the subject would be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would record this info and store it using the [Java Preferences API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html). Capture the resize using something like:

```
TableColumn col=table.getColumnModel().getTableColumn(colNumber);
col.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
   public void propertyChanged(PropertyChangeEvent e) {

      // has the column width changed ?
   }
});
```

Comment: The other option is to have a "Save" button that captures all the width and saves them to a file.  Also, this data could easily be stored in a database as well, if your application is already using one.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I do like this idea of using propertyChanged with Java Preferences API.